# Dynamic injection using property files in maven and spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin

I have a maven spring boot project and there are a few files under the `src/main/assets` folder that I need to edit during the build process.

I need to read the values from the property file or the property tag, and replace them in the files present in the assets folder.

For instance, if there is a file `hello.txt` under `src/main/assets` with variable placeholders like -

```
Hello ${name}
```

I need to read the "name" property and replace it in the `hello.txt` file.

How can I achieve this using maven?